# Android Widget method confusion

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget

Weeks after I decided to look into the android api to probably improve my knowledge of Java. I just realized i have actually been hiding alot from myself.

All I want ask is

```
Button button=findViewById();
```

It could be button or any widget or whatsoever(just for illustration), we then call a method of different type on it

```
button.setOnClickListener()
```

whereas button doesn't have any such method as **setOnClickListener** and afterall **setOnClickListener** is of type view.View. So am kinda lost.

Same as others(e.g image.setBackgroundResource)

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Button`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) class extends the `View` class:

```
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.Button
```

In the `View` class is defined the [`setOnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) method.
The `Button` class has own methods and **inherits** the methods from the `TextView` and the `View` classes like the `setOnClickListener`.

[image]

Comment: you did came to the rescue, i was looking at        public class Button extends android.widget.TextView without looking further